# Android Studio: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:fp9.0.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I try to compile I get this error 
"Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:fp9.0.0" in Android Studio. I am trying to include the play services in my project. This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "Application name"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:fp9.0.0'
}
```

The only thing I have changed in this file is this line:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:fp9.0.0'
```

I have installed Google Play Services and it's version number is 30.

Comment: What do you want to use from google play services?

Comment: I want to use the google maps api

Comment: Change it to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue yesterday. In the messages section when running a gradle sync or build, I got a message with an option to update something from the M2 repo. Clicking the link downloaded the latest version and fixed the issue.

You could also try `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'`

If you are only using maps, consider only downloading maps using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'` as it can save you hitting the 65K method dex limit later in development.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to add and change this in your Project Level `Gradle`.**

> Update `classpath` `com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0` to `classpath com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0`

**And**

> Also try to change compile `Dependencies` as below.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
```

> Or for map you can only use this.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
```

Comment: Where can I change the classpath?

Comment: In your Project level `Gradle` change this. if not added then add this.